# Goto error .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a simple game in batch and i keep getting a goto error when trying to go from :1 to :2 :3 or :4. I cant figure our what is wrong with it. Please tell me the problem. Thanks! P.S. I'm new to this.

```
:start
@echo off 
color a
echo Adventue V2 
echo 10/28/2013
pause
echo Name?
set /p name=
echo Hello %name%! Would you like to start (y/n)
set /p start=
if %start% == y goto 1
if %start% == Y goto 1
if %start% == n goto start
if %start% == N goto start

:1
echo Let us Begin...
echo The year is 1673 and you are living on a small farm. What do you do?
echo 1)Feed Chicken 2)Feed Cow 3)Fetch Water
set /p 1=
if %1% == 1 goto 2
if %1% == 2 goto 3
if %1% == 3 goto 4

:2
echo You go to the chicken pen and find one of your chickens has been killed by a fox. What do you do?
echo 1)Look For The Fox 2)Tell Your Father 3)Tell Your Mother
set /p 2=
if %2% == 1 goto 5
if %2% == 2 goto 6
if %2% == 3 goto 7

:3
echo You feed The cows and you find a coin purse. What do you do?
echo 1)Look In It 2)Leave It
set /p 3=
if %3% == 1 goto 8
if %3% == 2 goto 9

:4
echo You got to the well to fetch water but the well is empty. What do you do?
echo 1)Crawl Into It 2)Tell Your Parents
set /p 4=
if %4% == 1 goto 10
if %4% == 2 goto 11
```

Answer (score 2):

I think is because of your `%number%` that is causing the issue. Change your variable to `%variablename%` and this should work.

For example, instead of:

```
:1
echo Let us Begin...
echo The year is 1673 and you are living on a small farm. What do you do?
echo 1)Feed Chicken 2)Feed Cow 3)Fetch Water
set /p 1=
if %1% == 1 goto 2
if %1% == 2 goto 3
if %1% == 3 goto 4
```

change it to:

```
:1
echo Let us Begin...
echo The year is 1673 and you are living on a small farm. What do you do?
echo 1)Feed Chicken 2)Feed Cow 3)Fetch Water
set /p q1=
if %q1% == 1 goto 2
if %q1% == 2 goto 3
if %q1% == 3 goto 4
```

Comment: +1, Yes, `%1%` will be interpreted as parameter 1 (`%1`), followed by a lone `%` that will get stripped. In other words, parameters take precedence over variables when interpreting percents.